# PHP mailer - include path when folders are outside root

Tags: php, phpmailer

I had *phpmailer* running fine on a hosted server. I moved to a VPS which is **linux/ubuntu** so most of the installation is done via the console.

#### Previously my include was simply:

```
include('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
include('phpmailer/class.smtp.php');
```

Both those were inside the root folder, when i ran the install via the console it stored the files in `usr/shar/php/libphp-phpmailer`

---

I have never worked with files outside the root, is there a special way to reference them in `include()`?
For reference, my root folder is: `var/www/`

Comment: Have you tried to simply include that file using its entire path?

Comment: Aside from an [`open_basedir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) possibly blocking you there isn't anything special about including from outside the document root (and I'd recommend it to move _everything_ that isn't accessed _directly_ by the visitor outside that document root).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may work for you now

```
include('/usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
include('/usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer/class.smtp.php');
```

Since you have console access to that machine, cd in to /usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer and make sure those files are there. If they aren't, you can try to locate those files.

In ubuntu/debian you can find files using 'sudo updatedb; locate class.phpmailer.php' (updatedb ensures your file name database is up to date)

Answer (score 0):

use   the  following   `../` as move back to directory

like if are at  `www/html/`    and   want to access file  in `www/lib/`

```
include(../lib/filename) ;
```